# preceding-sibling with a twist

Tags: xslt

In the sample XML there are two forms that match on number and type; in the second matching form I need to blank out the `flag` element's value.   I cannot change the level I am iterating over due to some interrelated stylesheets.  I can do `preceding-sibling` if I were iterating on `formslist` but I can't seem to get the syntax correct when I am one level deeper on the `flag` element.  Both the number and type have to match before blanking it out.

```
<apply-templates match="formslist/flag">  
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=""></xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</apply-templates>
```

Sample XML

```
<forms>
    <formslist>
        <number>one</number>
        <type>car</type>
        <flag>da</flag>
    </formslist>
    <formslist>
        <number>two</number>
        <type>truck</type>
        <flag>ex</flag>
    </formslist>
    <formslist>
        <number>one</number>
        <type>car</type>
        <flag>da</flag>
    </formslist>
</forms>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If you want to get the `formslist` parent of your current `flag`, you should use `".."`. For a better answer you need to provide a desired output and a complete stylesheet.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFlag" match="formslist/flag"
  use="concat(../number, '+', ../type)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "flag/text()[generate-id(..)
           !=
            generate-id(key('kFlag',
                            concat(../../number,
                                   '+',
                                   ../../type
                                   )
                            )[1]
                        )
            ]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<forms>
    <formslist>
        <number>one</number>
        <type>car</type>
        <flag>da</flag>
    </formslist>
    <formslist>
        <number>two</number>
        <type>truck</type>
        <flag>ex</flag>
    </formslist>
    <formslist>
        <number>one</number>
        <type>car</type>
        <flag>da</flag>
    </formslist>
</forms>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<forms>
   <formslist>
      <number>one</number>
      <type>car</type>
      <flag>da</flag>
   </formslist> 
   <formslist>
      <number>two</number>
      <type>truck</type>
      <flag>ex</flag>
   </formslist>
   <formslist>
      <number>one</number>
      <type>car</type>
      <flag/>
   </formslist>
</forms>
```

**Do note** the use of the Muenchian method for grouping, which is significantly faster than using comparison to `preceding-sibling::*` (the last has a `O(N^2)` -- quadratical performance).

Answer (score 0):

When evaluated inside the template match for a `flag` this should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
    <xsl:variable name="thisFormslist" select=".." />
    <flag>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../preceding-sibling::*[$thisFormslist/number=number and $thisFormslist/type=type]">
                <!--number and type have been seen before, so don't put a value for this flag-->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </flag>
```

It creates a variable to reference the current `formslist` element and then uses it in the predicate filter to compare the `number` and `type` to the `preceding-sibling` elements of the parent element(`formslist`).